# Symfony 2 dynamically change form based on a selected value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, symfony

I have the following table:

```
Events:
 - Date (date)
 - EventType (varchar)
 - Value (varchar)
```

EventType can have a few values i.e check-in, checkout, room rent, misc, etc. I want to make a form that will change the field type of "Value" to text, date, or entity based on the selected type in "EventType". I tried to find some solutions but didn't succeed. [The only thing I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004759/dynamic-form-with-multiple-choice-fields-symfony2) is that I have to use queryBuilder but can't understand how to apply it here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use Event Subscribers, by adding an event subscriber to your Form, you delegate the creation of your fields to that Subscriber.
Inside your Event Subscriber your could check your "EventType" and add the appropriate "Value" field.

- [How to Dynamically Generate Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html)
- [Adding An Event Subscriber To A Form Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class)

Comment: I have looked for such way. Which form event should I use if I don't know what user going to select?

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution. I added `EventSubscriber` to my form and send ajax request with type which user has selected to let subscriber decide what kind of fields add.

```
$subscriber = new EventSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
$builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);

$builder->add('eventType', 'entity', array('class' => 'Bundle:EventType', 'property' => 'eventName', 'required' => true));
```

Thanks to Ahmed Siouani.